# FTP uploading 0 bytes

Tags: c#, ftp

**Situation**

I have some code that uploads a file, usually .csv in this case to a remote FTP site

**Code**

```
    try
    {
        /* Create an FTP Request */
        ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + remoteFile);
        /* Log in to the FTP Server with the User Name and Password Provided */
        ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
        /* When in doubt, use these options */
        ftpRequest.UseBinary = false;
        ftpRequest.UsePassive = false;
        ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        /* Specify the Type of FTP Request */
        ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
        ftpStream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream();
        /* Open a File Stream to Read the File for Upload */
        FileStream localFileStream = new FileStream(localFile, FileMode.Create);
        /* Buffer for the Downloaded Data */
        byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        int bytesSent = localFileStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
        /* Upload the File by Sending the Buffered Data Until the Transfer is Complete */
        try
        {
            while (bytesSent != 0)
            {
                ftpStream.Write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesSent);
                bytesSent = localFileStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
        /* Resource Cleanup */
        localFileStream.Close();
        ftpStream.Close();
        ftpRequest = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
    return;
}
```

**Issue**

The program makes a connection successfully, and appears to upload my file, but the .csv is empty and the filesize is 0 bytes. Is there anything in my code that could cause this?

Comment: How much is your buffer size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you finding that your local file is being truncated to 0 bytes, too?  I think the issue is here:

```
FileStream localFileStream = new FileStream(localFile, FileMode.Create);
```

You should be opening the file with `FileMode.Open` or `FileMode.OpenOrCreate`.  The [documentation for `FileMode.Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.filemode.aspx) states "If the file already exists, it will be overwritten." and "FileMode.Create is equivalent to requesting that if the file does not exist, use CreateNew; otherwise, use Truncate".

Comment: That's exactly what I was about to write - kudos to your speedy response!

Comment: Yes local file is also truncated just noticed, thanks I'll try this.